get variable in callback (by axios)
I have script like this,
   for (var i = 0; i < 10;i++){   
          axios.get(url).then(res=>{
              console.log("product connection success",i);
                                        
          }).catch(res=>{
              console.log("product connection error",res);
         });
            
   }

Always i returns 10, because this callback is called after i loop finished.
However I want to get the i when axios.get is called.
Is it possible? or how can I passed the certain data to callback?

Use let instead of var so that you get a separate i variable defined for each iteration.

You might want to give the server a break. Here is what I normally do because it is simpler and easier to understand: const urls = ['url1','url2'], len = urls.length, cnt = 0, getUrl = () => { if (cnt >= len) return; fetch(url[cnt]).then(res => { console.log(cnt,res); setTimeout(getUrl,100); }).catch(err => console.log(cnt,err)); getUrl();
